# I don't understand how it works

Tags: discord.py

I have a code that has the command "!forma", when I enter this command in the discord, informs me "[2024-02-10 23:37:21] [ ERROR ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "forma" is not found"

```
intents = discord.Intents.default().all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
class VerificationBot(commands.Bot):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default().all())

  @commands.command(name="forma")
  async def forma(self, ctx, nickname):
    """
    Обрабатывает команду "!forma" и отправляет запрос на верификацию.

    Args:
        ctx: контекст команды
        nickname: введенный никнейм
    """

    if not nickname:
      await ctx.send("**Ошибка!** Вы не указали никнейм. Пожалуйста, используйте команду `!forma` с вашим никнеймом.")
      return
```

I want the team to work

Comment: You're not registering anything with the bot you created from `commands.Bot`, and you're not creating any instance of `VerificationBot` in the code you've included - how are you actually running the code, and why do you expect a command to be registered?

Comment: Do you understand [how titles work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615)?

Answer (score -1):

First, are you importing `discord` and `commands`?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Also, remove the `all()` from `intents`. i.e.:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
```

If you are using the `@commands.command()` decorator then you need to call `bot.add_command(forma)` but the problem you'll run into is that everything is in the class. Personally, I would get it working without the class, and then add that or whatever else you need. The function though, `forma`, just put that outside the class and then `bot.add_command(forma)` should work.

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) is a link to the `DiscordPy` docs on commands.

This should be a good working starting point but I might have missed something.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@commands.command()
async def forma(ctx, nickname):
    """
    Обрабатывает команду "!forma" и отправляет запрос на верификацию.

    Args:
        ctx: контекст команды
        nickname: введенный никнейм
    """

    if not nickname:
      await ctx.send("**Ошибка!** Вы не указали никнейм. Пожалуйста, используйте команду `!forma` с вашим никнеймом.")
      return
    
    # TODO: nickname is set so add additional code here

bot.add_command(forma)
```